# ubuntu 21.10 upgrade apache sticking to php7.4

Tags: apache2, config, php-8, ubuntu-21.04

I upgraded from ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10.

apache2 does not change to php8 even after a2dismod php7.4 (...).
I get the following error.
I checked the config files in apache/ but could not find a line for it.

```
[Fri Jan 07 13:04:04.231832 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 1320] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed

[Fri Jan 07 13:04:04.231889 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1320] [client 127.0.0.1:50726] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: http://localhost/oodb...

[Fri Jan 07 13:04:04.780393 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 1319] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed

[Fri Jan 07 13:04:04.780431 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1319] [client 127.0.0.1:50728] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: http://localhost/...

[Fri Jan 07 13:04:06.829607 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 1318] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after using commands like below the problem remained.

- sudo systemctl enable php8-fpm
- sudo systemctl disable php7.4-fpm

Only after manually deleting the link `conf-enabled/php7.4-fpm.conf` (/etc/apache2) and setting symoblic link (`sudo ln -s ../conf-available/php8.0-fpm.conf`) apache worked (after restart).

Comment: What directory were you in when you ran these commands? "conf-enabled" sounds like a directory managed by one of Ubuntu's enable/disable scripts, e.g. `a2enconf`/`a2disconf`

Comment: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled resp. /etc/apache2/

Comment: Right, I guessed as much. a2enconf and a2disconf are definitely the commands you needed, then - they work just like the a2enmod / a2dismod you'd already tried, but for a different directory of config files